# Unable to declare variable

Tags: java, android

Why I'm unable to declare variable in MessageViewHolder class? I want to findviewById for my xml file. BTW I'm running latest version of Android Studio in latest 64 bit Ubuntu. But, surely there is no problem with version. I tried with some other variable. Same problem!

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false);

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Messages messages = messagesList.get(position);
        holder.chatText.setText(messages.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

  public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView chatText;
        public CircleImageView chatImage;


        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }

        chatText =
        chatImage
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do **`findViewById`** inside **`MessageViewHolder()`** Using  `itemView`

Try this

```
public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView chatText;
        public CircleImageView chatImage;


        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

          chatText =itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatText);
          chatImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatImage);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In view holder you take id's from view

So it is -

```
public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   chatText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.*);
   chatImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.*);
}
```